# Pls explain this part of meyer's reset in details and is it useful to keep this while it's not supperted in IE?

Tags: css

Pls explain this part of meyer's reset  in details and is it useful to keep this while it's not supperted in IE?

I think this is not supported by below IE8 then what is the benefit to use this keep this in css reset.

and even if we keep then what about IE?

```
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {content: "";}
blockquote, q {quotes: "" "";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with progressive enhancement. For example, use this for the browsers it works for, and for IE7 and below use conditional stylesheets and stick a background image that looks like quotes or something. Or leave it without quotes and put it in italics or whatever will keep it making some sort of sense.

Things don't need to be ideal for the more limited browsers as long as the visitors using them can't tell that something is actually wrong. As long as it's usable and makes sense for them then feel free to use any cool tricks that only show up in superior browsers.

Comment: is there any way to give same effect in IE without using images?

Comment: @Jitendra I don't think you understand the CSS you're reading up there. Give it a close look. It's resetting it.

Comment: @D_N - could you explain this please? Thanks. you are right I know these pseudo-elements are not supported in all browser. but not getting property benefit of this part of reset.

Comment: You need to provide the content. Right now that CSS is telling it to put nothing before or after quotes. See this article: http://monc.se/kitchen/129/rendering-quotes-with-css

Comment: @metal-gear-solid Re: doing it without images... I'm fairly certain you can do it for IE<=7with javascript without too much trouble, but I'm not the right guy to tell you how. And there's also the whole "thinking outside the box" thing... how can you make it look like a quote without actual quotes? As long as the users understand what's going on it doesn't have to have explicit quotes.